# Does IIS have a SRV _SERVICE record?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, ip, domain, srv-record

This may seem an odd question but I don't full understand SRV records. I am basically trying to point:

`something.example.com` to and IP like `111.111.111.111:8089`

I have done something similar for a minecraft server using the _MINECRAFT service.

Is this possible by any means for a website hosted on IIS?

I am using IIS7 and will have port forwarding via my router as well if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SRV records can be used by clients to lookup the location of a service (by hostname and port; as well as some other details). Any service can be looked up this way.

For a web server it would be `_http._tcp.example.com`.

I don't know of any web browser that looks up SRV records however, so setting it would be pretty useless. Minecraft clients specifically support SRV records, which is why it works there. Several other protocols require or strongly suggest that clients support SRV records too (XMPP for example).

Comment: Right, that's pretty much what I thought would be the case. Is there any other way to point a domain to an IP:PORT combination?

Comment: Nope. Web browsers will use port 80 unless the url specifically includes a different port.